# Installing Mockito using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, mockito

I have installed Gradle by adding the path to it into the system variables. I am quite new to Java and this is the first time that I am trying to install an external library for it. On the Mockito web-page, they say that one can:

> Declare a dependency on “mockito-core” library using your favorite
>   build system. With Gradle one can do:
>
> ```
> repositories { jcenter() }
> dependencies { testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+" }
> ```

So I have no idea what it means. I changed the directory in cmd to the Gradle folder and tried to execute these commands, but that is not how one is supposed to do it. Can you give me a hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a build.gradle file where you can insert the dependency. I recommend using an ide like [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which can generate a gradle project for you so you don't have to do this manually. Just install the corresponding Gradle Plugin. This also makes sure you have a correct project structure.

Comment: I've got IntelliJ actually. What do i do then?

Comment: Usually Gradle is bundled with IntelliJ. To see if it's activated go to Settings > Plugins and search for "Gradle". If not, activate it and restart IntelliJ. Now you can create a new Project with Gradle (Select "Gradle" in the New Project Wizard) and copy your existing sources to the new Project (to folder src/java).